# Manipulate cell width in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

This is something of a nitpick, but I'm having some trouble getting to grips with `tikz-cd`. I'm not sure of the TikZ terminology, but I think I'm trying to find a way to manipulate cell widths. Here's a minimal example to illustrate my problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \rar \dar & B \rar \dar & C \dar \\
    D \rar      & E \rar      & F \oplus G
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my MWE]

I'd like to make the arrow from `B` to `C` the same length as that from `E` to `F+G`. My first thought was that I should pad the box (cell?) containing `C` so it's the same width as the one containing F + G. I can sort of do it by replacing `C` with `\quad C \quad`, but surely there must be a better way! Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Sure, you can set `C` inside a box that is exactly the width of `F \oplus G`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \rar \dar & B \rar \dar & \makebox[\widthof{$F \oplus G$}]{$C$} \dar \\
    D \rar      & E \rar      & F \oplus G
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc)'s command `\widthof` is used to measure the width of `F \oplus G`, setting `C` in a centred box of that exact width.

Answer (score 7):

You have to fool `tikz-cd` into thinking that the lower right corner object has zero width; then you can artificially shorten the arrow to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow{r} \arrow{d} & B \arrow{r} \arrow{d} & C \arrow{d} \\
  D \arrow{r}           & E \arrow[end anchor={[xshift=-1.25em]}]{r}
  & \mathclap{F \oplus G}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The command `\mathclap` is provided by `mathtools`.

[image]

Sincerely, I prefer the default version.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice way of doing it - not quite what I had in mind but it seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Not a new problem:

- [How to ensure consecutive diagonal arrows form a straight line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89056/16595)
- [Tikz-cd: How can I arrange diagonal arrows parallel?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130780/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}\centering
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \rar \dar & B \rar \dar & C \dar \\
    D \rar      & E \rar      & F \oplus G
\end{tikzcd}\medskip\par
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \rar \dar & B \rar \dar & |[text width=width("$F\oplus G$"), align=center]|C \dar \\
    D \rar      & E \rar      & F \oplus G
\end{tikzcd}\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}
    A \rar \dar & B \rar \dar & C \dar \\
    D \rar      & E \rar      & |[overlay]| F \oplus G
\end{tikzcd}\medskip\par
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes=overlay, row sep=large, column sep=large]
    A \rar \dar & B \rar \dar & C \dar \\
    D \rar      & E \rar      & F \oplus G
\end{tikzcd}\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/column sep=
         {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/column sep/large},between origins}]
    A \rar \dar & B \rar \dar & C \dar \\
    D \rar      & E \rar      & F \oplus G
\end{tikzcd}\bigskip
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]